# How create trigger statement to insert values into SQL Server table only if does not yet exist?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-delete

I am using SQL Server 2014. I have the following code to create a trigger (it insert data):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[INSERT_TR_LAB_TESTS_RESULTS]
ON [dbo].[TRANSACTIONS_TBL]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @SERVICE_CODE INT
    DECLARE @INVOICE_NO INT
    DECLARE @PATIENT_TYPE_ID INT
    DECLARE @INSURANCE_COMPANY_ID INT
    DECLARE @INSURANCE_CARD_NO VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @SPONSER_TYPE_ID INT
    DECLARE @QTY_OF_SERVICES INT
    DECLARE @PATIENT_NAME_ID INT
    DECLARE @LAB_TEST_CATEGORY_ID INT
    DECLARE @LAB_TEST_NAME nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @LAB_TEST_RESULT VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @RESULT_REFERENCE_VALUE nvarchar(70)
    DECLARE @TEST_UNIT nvarchar(50)

    INSERT INTO LAB_TESTS_RESULTS (SERVICE_CODE, INVOICE_NO, PATIENT_TYPE_ID, 
                                   INSURANCE_COMPANY_ID, INSURANCE_CARD_NO, 
                                   SPONSER_TYPE_ID, QTY_OF_SERVICES, PATIENT_NAME_ID, 
                                   LAB_TEST_CATEGORY_ID, LAB_TEST_NAME, 
                                   LAB_TEST_RESULT, RESULT_REFERENCE_VALUE, TEST_UNIT)
        SELECT  
            t1.SERVICE_CODE, t1.INVOICE_NO, t1.PATIENT_TYPE_ID,
            t1.INSURANCE_COMPANY_ID, t1.INSURANCE_CARD_NO,
            t1.SPONSER_TYPE_ID, t1.QTY_OF_SERVICES, t1.PATIENT_NAME_ID,
            t2.LAB_TEST_CATEGORY_ID, t2.LAB_TEST_NAME,
            t2.LAB_TEST_RESULT, t2.RESULT_REFERENCE_VALUE, t2.TEST_UNIT
        FROM    
            TRANSACTIONS_TBL t1
        CROSS JOIN 
            LAB_TESTS_NAMES_TBL t2 
        WHERE   
            t1.SERVICE_CODE = t2.SERVICE_CODE
GO
```

How do I insert values only if does not yet exist else update them?

Comment: what is the key of your table, is it `SERVICE_CODE` ?

Comment: You need to have a look at the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables inside your trigger - those contains the rows being inserted, deleted or updated. Based on those rows, you can insert and/or update other rows .... but for simplicity's sake, I'd really recommend having **three separate** triggers - one for each type of operation (`FOR INSERT` - only inserts new rows; `FOR UPDATE` only updates existing rows, and `FOR DELETE` only deletes existing rows).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the key of your table is `SERVICE_CODE`, follow the next approach:-

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LAB_TESTS_RESULTS WHERE SERVICE_CODE = @SERVICE_CODE)
    BEGIN
            -- Put your update statement here
    End
Else
    BEGIN
            -- Put your Insert statement here
    End
```

**The Complete Code:-**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[INSERT_TR_LAB_TESTS_RESULTS]
ON [dbo].[TRANSACTIONS_TBL]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @SERVICE_CODE INT
    DECLARE @INVOICE_NO INT
    DECLARE @PATIENT_TYPE_ID INT
    DECLARE @INSURANCE_COMPANY_ID INT
    DECLARE @INSURANCE_CARD_NO VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @SPONSER_TYPE_ID INT
    DECLARE @QTY_OF_SERVICES INT
    DECLARE @PATIENT_NAME_ID INT
    DECLARE @LAB_TEST_CATEGORY_ID INT
    DECLARE @LAB_TEST_NAME nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @LAB_TEST_RESULT VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @RESULT_REFERENCE_VALUE nvarchar(70)
    DECLARE @TEST_UNIT nvarchar(50)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LAB_TESTS_RESULTS WHERE SERVICE_CODE = @SERVICE_CODE)
    BEGIN
        Update LAB_TESTS_RESULTS
        Set 
             INVOICE_NO = @INVOICE_NO,
             PATIENT_TYPE_ID = @PATIENT_TYPE_ID ,
             INSURANCE_COMPANY_ID = @INSURANCE_COMPANY_ID,
             INSURANCE_CARD_NO = @INSURANCE_CARD_NO,
             SPONSER_TYPE_ID = @SPONSER_TYPE_ID,
             QTY_OF_SERVICES = @QTY_OF_SERVICES,
             PATIENT_NAME_ID = @PATIENT_NAME_ID,
             LAB_TEST_CATEGORY_ID = @LAB_TEST_CATEGORY_ID,
             LAB_TEST_NAME = @LAB_TEST_NAME,
             LAB_TEST_RESULT = @LAB_TEST_RESULT,
             RESULT_REFERENCE_VALUE = @RESULT_REFERENCE_VALUE,
             TEST_UNIT = @TEST_UNIT
        Where 
            SERVICE_CODE = @SERVICE_CODE
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO LAB_TESTS_RESULTS (SERVICE_CODE, INVOICE_NO, PATIENT_TYPE_ID, INSURANCE_COMPANY_ID, INSURANCE_CARD_NO, SPONSER_TYPE_ID, QTY_OF_SERVICES, PATIENT_NAME_ID, LAB_TEST_CATEGORY_ID, LAB_TEST_NAME, LAB_TEST_RESULT, RESULT_REFERENCE_VALUE, TEST_UNIT)
        SELECT  
            t1.SERVICE_CODE, t1.INVOICE_NO, t1.PATIENT_TYPE_ID,
            t1.INSURANCE_COMPANY_ID, t1.INSURANCE_CARD_NO,
            t1.SPONSER_TYPE_ID, t1.QTY_OF_SERVICES, t1.PATIENT_NAME_ID,
            t2.LAB_TEST_CATEGORY_ID, t2.LAB_TEST_NAME,
            t2.LAB_TEST_RESULT, t2.RESULT_REFERENCE_VALUE, t2.TEST_UNIT
        FROM    
            TRANSACTIONS_TBL t1
        CROSS JOIN 
            LAB_TESTS_NAMES_TBL t2 
        WHERE   
            t1.SERVICE_CODE = t2.SERVICE_CODE
    END

GO
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed Abdelqader for your answer
But the problem is after new insertion to TRANSACTIONS_TBL table 
The trigger insert the new records with old records (reinsert the records) to the LAB_TESTS_RESULTS table